# GMSMarkerOptions changes location when zooming the Map

Tags: ios6, annotations, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using Google maps sdk for ios6 
i have been able to succesfully add the maps draw poly line paths
and add a marker annotation.
But the problem arises when i start zooming the map
GMSMarkerOptions annotation changes its location slightly from the original position
Has anyone encountered the same problem?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the marker's `groundAnchor` property anchors the marker to the map underneath during zooming.